# Get upper XML Node Value depending on attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes

I'm just trying to write a XSL 1.0 Code (transforming XML with XSLT) which allows me to give out an attribute value depending on a low level attribute.
To make this clear, an example might be useful:

```
<age_list>
  <age i="13">
    <type j="min"/>
  </age>
  <age i="22">
    <type j="max"/>
  <age_list>
</age_list>
```

So, I want to extract the age's attribute i but I need to know whether it's a min or max age as, for example, some movies are prohibited for kids younger than 18 but the recommended age is 12 though. 
So quite each movie has an age list but not every age list contains min AND max age, sometimes there is just max, sometimes just min and sometimes even both.
If min is not given, it's automatically set to 0 while the value of max is set to 999 if it's not given.
So, how could I achieve this?

I iterate through all age lists and do the following test:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./age/type[@j='MIN']">
        <xsl:value-of select="./age/@j" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./age/type[@j='MAX']">
        <xsl:value-of select="./age/@j" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>999</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But it's getting me for max and min the same value which sounds logical as I refer to the current age and not depending on the attribute j of type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML and XSLT is case-sensitive. In the XML your `j` attribute has a value of `min` but in your XSLT you are looking for `MIN` which is different.

Also, your code first tests for an `age` attribute of a given type, but the `xsl:when` does not change your current context, which means when you do `<xsl:value-of select="./age/@j" />` you are just getting the very first `age` element, not the one with of the required type.

Try this instead:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="age[type/@j='min']">
        <xsl:value-of select="age[type/@j='min']/@i" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="age[type/@j='max']">
        <xsl:value-of select="age[type/@j='max']/@i" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>999</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

You could avoid the repeated expression with a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="min" select="age[type/@j='min']" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$min">
        <xsl:value-of select="$min/@i" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:variable name="max" select="age[type/@j='max']" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$max">
        <xsl:value-of select="$max/@i" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>999</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! This works fluently! Im new to XSLT, that's why I don't know how to reach specific node attributes and values. The way of thinking is so much different than programming java or stuff like that.